# Adding RestSharp.MonoDroid to solution

Tags: mono, restsharp, xamarin

Sorry for the beginner question, but I am not familiar with mono. I need to create `REST` client for `Android` in `Xamarin` and I want to add `RestSharp` framework to the solution. How do I do it? In Java, I just added jar file to project, have no idea, how I do it here.
I already downloaded `RestSharp.Monodroid` solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using Visual Studio 2010 as an IDE. If yes, then this answer applies.

Right click on the project in which you want to use RestSharp library then click on **Add Reference...** and browse for RestSharp dll. This is how you add references in Visual Studio.